# SQL Server update set amount = (positive numeric) + (negative numeric) increases amount? Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, set, numeric

I'm performing an update from a global temp table like this:

```
update some_table
set Amount = (##GlobalTable.InitialAmount) + (##GlobalTable.[Difference])
from ##GlobalTable
where Amount = ##GlobalTable.InitialAmount
```

The Amount, InitialAmount, and Difference columns are all numeric(21,2)

The Amount and InitialAmount are always positive.  The problem is that when the Difference is negative the resulting Amount is actually increased by the negative difference.  It should be performing subtraction, but it's not.  When Difference is positive it works fine.  Any ideas why this is happening?

I'm on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64 bit using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Please provide example data for `some_table` and `##GlobalTable` that demonstrate the issue. BTW the `UPDATE ... FROM` syntax can cause undeterministic results if more than one possible row in `##GlobalTable` matches the row in `some_table`

Comment: what do you mean by "when difference is negative"?

Comment: As an aside, why are you using a global ##temp table? Are you intentionally killing concurrency instead of using a local #temp table?

Answer (score 0):

One way this can happen...(but may not be what you are seeing)

See if you have two rows in ##GlobalTable with the same value for InitialAmount but different values for Difference.

If so, then a row in some_table may match both (or more) rows in ##GlobalTable, and  SQLServer makes no guarantee what answer you will get.

In my experience SQLServer will choose a row to use in the update and it is usually the last qualifying row retrieved from ##GlobalTable based on the execution plan. Since the execution plan is subject to change as table contents change the result is not so predicable, and not something to count on when writing code.

Unless you know that each row in ##GlobalTable has a unique value for InitialAmount, you should choose a more reliable way to join some_table with ##GlobalTable.